# Apache AliasMatch with Wildcard Not Working As Intended

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, alias, mod-alias

I am trying map all wildcards for a directory `/a/*` onto on file `article.php` using `AliasMatch ^/a/(.*) /article.php` but without redirecting (I want to keep the url looking the same). But I am getting a `The requested URL was not found on this server.` error.

Is **AliasMatch** even the right way to do this? Or is there a better way.

I am trying to achieve something like:

```
example.com/a/hello
example.com/a/this-is-an-article
```

**article.php**

```
echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

*result*:

```
hello
this-is-an-article
```

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [END,L,R=permanent]
 AliasMatch ^/a/(.*) /article.php
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`AliasMatch` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch);

> Description:  Maps URLs to filesystem locations using regular expressions
>
> Syntax:   `AliasMatch regex file-path|directory-path`

You are referencing an URL path instead of the required filesystem path; the file is not located at `/article.php` in you filesystem.

Try:

```
AliasMatch "^/a/(.*)" "/var/www/html/article.php"
```

Furthermore, you are first redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS with mod_rewrite ([you should use mod_alias instead](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect)), but your `AliasMatch` is in the HTTP `<VirtualHost *:80>`. It is never used.

Full fixed example configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    AliasMatch "^/a/(.*)" "/var/www/html/article.php"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```